# Proper link is not shared using facebook link sharer

Tags: php, facebook, url

I am trying to share the following link:

**https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com/test.php/?user=abc&serial=43215**

The sharing is ok.But when I am opening the link from facebook, It is not showing the correct link.

Showing like the following link:

http://www.example.com/test.php/?user=abc

and removed these part from the shared link : **&serial=43215** .

How can I get the original link like **http://www.example.com/test.php/?user=abc&serial=43215**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) to check your URL and be sure of what is wrong. You should ensure you are setting the correct `og` tags which are included in your page's header tag. Verify these then you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are putting one URL as a parameter value into another URL, you must of course properly URL-encode that first URL.

The way you are doing it right now, you are passing *two* parameters to sharer.php – parameter `u` with value `http://www.example.com/test.php/?user=abc` and parameter `serial` with value `43215`.

Since your question includes the tag `php`, you can simply use `urlencode` for this:

```
$shareUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' .
             urlencode('http://www.example.com/test.php/?user=abc&serial=43215');
```